# Paper about signal-to-noise ratio for LIGO/VIRGO

Tags: ligo, gravitational-wave-detectors

I am looking for a recent paper in which the signal-to-noise ratio for the ground based advanced LIGO/VIRGO interferometers is discussed, on the same line of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0512160) (dated 2006 by E. Berti et al.) about the SNR for LISA.

I have found [this old paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9701039) (dated 1997, by Flanagan & Huges) which estimates the SNR for LIGO/VIRGO, but it is too old (it is almost thirty years old): is there anything more recent?

What I want to do is calculate the SNR for the ring-down phase of different sources  and compare them with that of a Schwarzschild BH.

Comment: Hi mattiav27. The way you use singular case _I am looking for a recent paper_ instead of plural _I am looking for recent papers_ makes me wonder whether you are looking for a particular paper (that you e.g. have seen before but don't recall its author etc), or whether any recent papers on the matter will do?

Comment: @Qmechanic I am not looking for a particular paper, any recent article which explains how to calculate the SNR will do

Comment: Eq 1.1 of Flanagan and Hughes is the correct formula to use, assuming you have a perfect template for the ringdown. You "just" need to modify this formula by taking the lower frequency cutoff to be the start of the ringdown. In fact the subtlety is in defining this starting frequency. There is some discussion of this, for instance, in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.06784.pdf (sec 5.1)

Comment: The SNR calculation is well established so I don't understand why you require a recent paper to explain it.